# DevExpress GridView Select & replace item in Cell?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Is there a way like in Windows Textbox control to replace the selected text with in a cell? I know that an entire cell can be done with *SetRowCellValue*, but what about just a selection?

Thanks

Comment: can you please  explain more in detail what your trying to do?

Comment: Heimish, for example, my end intention is when a user selects a cell to edit, and selects some text in that cell, then clicks a menu item such as "Insert Time", the text selected in the cell is replaced with the Time for example.

I need to know how to "replace" the selected text in the active cell basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user edits a cell, an editor is used. So, you can get it using the GridView.ActiveEditor property:

```
if (gridView1.ActiveEditor == null || !(gridView1.ActiveEditor is TextEdit))
    return;
TextEdit editor = (TextEdit)gridView1.ActiveEditor;
editor.SelectedText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks so much Gosha, I appreciate it! I noticed that on DateEdit fields, it won't put anything, but TextEdit fields it works perfectly. Is there a trick to this?